# Adding position fixed breaks alignment of nav

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #333;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-list-item {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="logo">
            <h3>My Name</h3>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-list-item">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-list-item">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-list-item">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-list-item">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```

I want to have a menu that is position at the center and have it fixed as i scroll down. but for some reason, after adding a position fixed to it. it breaks the actual alignment and i dont have any idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `width: 100%` to your `header` class:

```
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%
}
```